# schema mongoose Required field if otherfield is true

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have mongoose schema like this:

```
var SomeSchema = new Schema({
    //Indicates whether the field failed import.
    importFailed: {type: Boolean, "default": false},

    //Represents the error message.
    errorMessage: {type: String}
});
```

please help me, how to make schema field "errorMessage" is **required** if field "importFailed" is true.

thanks before